# How do I access a local version of a website built in Python/Django on a Mac?

Tags: python, django, macos

Our web developer recently left, and I am trying to open a website he had been developing. I am new to Python, and just barely have my head around it on a Windows machine, but when I try to find it on the Mac I am lost. I dont even know where to start.

Could someone please advise me on how to open it on a local host? I am trying to view the pages he had already finished, but dont know to. I know where the files/folder structure is, but other than that, I am lost.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is the server instance running on the Mac or the Win pc?  Have you tried connecting to the local IP of the host machine?

Comment: What makes you think it's different on a Mac? If you know how to start the dev server on Windows, what happens when you try that on the Mac?

Comment: This should help - http://gpiot.com/blog/mac-os-x-lion-the-perfect-setup-for-python-django/

Comment: The server instance is running on the Mac. I did not access it on the PC, just did some tutorials on Python and Django. 
It's basically fear that I am going to break something already established. He worked on it for a long time, I know that it is already created, I just dont know how to see a live preview of what was created.

Comment: My advice - get another experienced python/django dev as it sounds like you aren't confident on the OSX. There are a multitude of things to learn, especially if they have been working on the site for a while, dependant libraries, virtualenv, IDE, etc etc.

Comment: was it checked into version control of any kind? Is it running on the machine now (can you hit localhost:8000 ?) Have you tried a ```ps -ef | grep python``` to see any running python jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diving into a Django development book called "Practical Django Projects" by James Bennett I discovered this:

> In order to open a site on localhost you need first need to start the server. Do this by opening the terminal and running
>
> ```
> python manage.py runserver
> ```
>
> Then you should be able to open a web browser and visit the address:
>
> ```
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/
> ```
>
> By default, the development web server runs on your computers local "loopback" network address, which is always 127.0.0.1, and binds to port 8000.